# Offline install of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a slow internet connection in my home. But I have fast connection at my office . So, what are the tools, I needed to download ,as a  beginner, for android apps development. I know that I need android studio, java and SDK.Is there any other tools that I need as a beginner?

Comment: No, these will get you started.

Comment: Andriod SDK is included in set up of android studio Itself

Comment: What about all the gradle/maven packages?

Comment: If you have any old SDK, then you can install it offline.

Comment: I started but cause rendering problems.

Comment: Anyway what are these gradle/maven .Can I download zip of it??

Comment: Gradle/mave is just a import thing..I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to download All Android Studio Packages on the bottom of the [website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) but when you are installing that it download some parts from the internet but not even close to the 1Gb of Android Studio, it have included already the sdk and other things.

When you have already installed the Android Studio if you want extras like others emulators from older versions or other plugins, you can install later on your office or try with your internet because some things are not big.

Comment: Thanks..its really easy..I was just being numb.